# Showing that Euclidean domain is UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $D$ be euclidean domain. We claim the following:

$1)$ Every element of $D$ can be expressed as a product of irreducible elements

$2)$ Every irreducible element of $D$ is a prime element.

From these two facts the claim follows. I had no problems understanding the second one. But the proof for the first proposition goes as follows:

Let $a \in D$, $a \neq 0$ and assume that $a=a_1a_2...a_k$ and none of the $a_i$ is a unit. Then from the lemma above we get ($\phi$ is the euclidean norm)$$\phi(a)>\phi(a_2a_3...a_k)>\phi(a_3a_4...a_k)>...>\phi(a_k)>\phi(1).$$
and thus $\phi(a)\geq k$. So the amount of factors in $a$ is bounded and we can find the maximal amount of factors.

Two questions: How does it follow that $\phi(a)\geq k$ and why this shows that the amount of factors is bounded?

Comment: @egreg That's true, just a typo. And thanks! Forgot that the domain of the norm function is natural numbers :(

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean by a Euclidean norm (what defining properties it has). The comment be egreg says $\phi(1) \ge 1$, but for the Euclidean domain $K[x]$ for a field $K$ its standard Euclidean function is $\phi(f) = \deg f$, for which $\phi(1) = 0$.

Comment: @KCd Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: @KCd I think the only property you need from it is that it's domain is natural numbers.

Comment: You mean its *range* is the natural numbers. But that is not all. You are also implicitly assuming $\phi(xy) \ge \phi(x)$ for all nonzero $x$ and $y$ in $D$. Not all definitions of a Euclidean domain in the literature make that assumption (see Dummit & Foote).

Comment: @KCd So if you take a more general definition it'd be easier to prove Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ PID $\Rightarrow$ UFD, I assume? Because I can't see how to take the direct route.

Comment: No, the more general (i.e., weaker-sounding) definition is absolutely the same, in the sense that a Euclidean domain where $\phi$ takes values in $\mathbf N$ but does not satisfy $\phi(xy) \ge \phi(x)$ all the time also has another function $\phi'$ that does satisfy such an inequality all the time. So whether you want to start off assuming such an inequality is just a matter of taste. I think it is easier to prove Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ UFD directly than to treat the PID case along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's notationally better to remove elements from the tail:
$$
\phi(a)>\phi(a_1\dots a_{k-1})>\phi(a_1\dots a_{k-2})>
\dots>\phi(a_1a_2)>\phi(a_1)>\phi(1)
$$
Thus, since $\phi(1)\ge0$, you get $\phi(a_1)\ge1$, $\phi(a_1a_2)\ge2$ and so on, until you get
$$\phi(a)=\phi(a_1a_2\dots a_k)\ge k.$$
We just use the fact that if $a>b$, then $a\ge b+1$.

Thus no factorization of $a$ can contain more than $\phi(a)$ factors.

Comment: It's all clear now. Thanks. Will accept when possible.